# Printer prints only once after each reboot or re-plugging of USB cable

Tags: 14.04, usb, printing, hp

I'm trying to get HP LaserJet 600 m602 working on Lubuntu 14.04 machine to which it is connected with USB cable. It prints first job ok, but when I send another job it behaves as if it is disconnected, until I reboot or unplug and re-plug the usb cable. After that it also prints only one job (either the one I sent previously if I release it, or a new one if I delete old one from the queue).

It is interesting that replugging USB cable only works if done at the end where it is connected to the printer. The cable is extension USB cable which on the other end connects to the shorter cable, which goes to printer. If I disconnect end reconnect extension cable from the smaller cable, or smaller cable from the printer, it doesn't work. It only works at the machine's end, but this behavior seems too consistent and specific to be caused by the faulty cable.

Extension cable is Delock 82446 Cable USB 2.0 Extension, active 10m.

Here's my cupsd.conf file:

```
LogLevel warn
MaxLogSize 1m
# Allow remote access
Port 631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock
Browsing On
BrowseLocalProtocols dnssd
DefaultAuthType Basic
WebInterface Yes
<Location />
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin>
  # Allow remote administration...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  # Allow remote access to the configuration files...
  Order allow,deny
  Allow all
</Location>
<Policy default>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
<Policy authenticated>
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
MaxJobs 50
```

Here's my printers.conf file:

```
# Printer configuration file for CUPS v1.7.2
# Written by cupsd
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE WHEN CUPSD IS RUNNING
<Printer ThPhyPrint>
UUID urn:uuid:9674b29c-6fbe-33f6-7dd6-8e4d0a1baca2
Info 
Location 
MakeModel HP LaserJet 600 M601 M602 M603 Postscript (recommended)
DeviceURI hp:/usb/HP_LaserJet_600_M602?serial=CNBVD26086
PPDTimeStamp *
State Idle
StateTime 1424099214
Type 8425684
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
ColorManaged Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</Printer>
```

Also, when opening print dialog box, Evince (PDF viewer I use) sometimes says "Authentication is required to get attributes of printer print" and requires username and password once or twice, but behavior seems independent of whether I enter username and password or simply press cancel button.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that motherboard is probably too old (Asus P4P800) and isn't giving enough power to the cable. Hitting `lsusb` kept showing the printer until the printing was done, so probably the final communication was killing the connection.

Old motherboard seems to be the culprit because plugging USB hub with external power supply (acting as sort of "prosthesis" for old motherboard) into computer and plugging the cable into the hub solved the problem.